# add a link separator or a small icon between the categories in main menu

Tags: magento-2.1, category, menu, ultimo

Actually i have two question regarding the categories being added in the menu in the header.

1. I want to add a `/` sign between the menu categories. As these categories are begin added from the admin panel how can i achieve this. how to.
2. On hover it completely change the background. I only want to show a small black base on hovering the category.

Any kind of help would be much appreciated. i am using ultimo theme.

Comment: do you need a bottom line on hove ?

Comment: yeah a bottom line and a / sign between the categories.

Comment: bottom line can be come and separator " | " you can use css border right

Comment: i dont understand your answer. sorry

Comment: give border-right to menu items , and hide for last child

Comment: actually i have done that but this is not possible for the `/`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/66007/discussion-between-manoj-deswal-and-tech-geek).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can do this using css. I don't have access to ultimo on Magento 2 but I guess it's pretty much like Magento 1.x in which case it would be something like:

```
.nav-regular li.level0 > a::after {content:"/"}
```

to not show the content after the last item use:

```
.nav-regular li.level0:last-of-type > a::after {content:""}
```

not quite sure what you mean by "show a small black base on hovering the category" but try:

```
.nav-regular li.level0 > a:hover {border-bottom:5px #000 solid}
```

Comment: let me try this.

Comment: it is adding but it is not being styled like i want to give a padding and margin so it should not stick with the words. It is appearing as `HOME/` i want to have like this `Home    /      Clothes`

Comment: You're probably going to have to edit the menu template file then and put the "/" character in. The file you'll need to be looking in is probably on your server at frontend/ultimo/default/template/infortis/ultramegamenu/navigation.phtml

Comment: no there is nothing like to add in that file and this file is located in code.

Comment: OK, you might have to contact Infortis then to see how to do it. Sorry can't be any more help

Comment: i got the solution . only problem is it is appending the content after the last li child

Comment: post the solution so others can see?

Comment: `.nav-regular li.level0.nav-2> a::after {
  content: "/";
  margin-left: 15px;
  font-size: 20px;
  color: #e1e1e1;
}
`
Just give a margin. For the removing last child i used a hack but not a pefer way. I mentioned this with every class.

Comment: I've edited my answer to show how you can get rid of it on the last li

Comment: Thank you for your help. If possible can you please also provide the solution of the hover problem?

Comment: Edited my answer